# NSWindow doesn't respond until click

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drag-and-drop, nswindow

I've got an image editor window. After drag event I minimize my window to miniature in the bottom left corner, after drop on the miniature I return window back. Above the miniature I change cursor to `operationNotAllowedCursor`.

The problem is: `NSWindow` does not change the cursor on miniature after the first `draggingEntered` (after the second and more everything's fine). Moreover, after drop on the miniature NSWindow does not receive any events until a click on any area of it.

Code for minimizing window (in NSWindow subclass):

```
-(void)minimize
{        
    const double miniSize = 240;
    MSDraggingMiniature *mini = [[MSDraggingMiniature alloc] init];
    [mini setMiniImage:[[MSScreenMaker getInstance] makeEditorScreen:(int)[self windowNumber]]];

    _mainContentView = self.contentView;
    _oldFrame = [self frame];
    [self setStyleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask];
    self.contentView = mini;
    NSRect drect = [[self screen] frame];
    double width, height;
    if (self.frame.size.width < self.frame.size.height) {
        height = miniSize;
        width = self.frame.size.width / self.frame.size.height * miniSize;
    } else {
        width = miniSize;
        height = self.frame.size.height / self.frame.size.width * miniSize;
    }
    _anima = MSEditorResizeAnimationMinimize;
    [self setFrame:NSMakeRect(drect.origin.x + 20, drect.origin.y + 20 , width, height) display:YES animate:YES];
}
-(void)deminimize
{
    self.contentView = _mainContentView;
    [self setStyleMask:NSTitledWindowMask];
    _anima = MSEditorResizeAnimationDeminimize;
    [self setFrame:_oldFrame display:YES animate:YES];

    [self makeKeyWindow];
    [self makeMainWindow];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of variants I found the answer. It seems that area, acting like Dragging Source, must be just `NSView`, not a subclass of `NSButton`, which I had.

I rewrote my Dragging Source class - now everything works fine.